# How to write unit test case for keyholder and PreparedStatementCreator 100%

Tags: junit, jdbctemplate

```
jdbcTemplate.update(new PreparedStatementCreator() {
        @Override
        public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection connection)
            throws SQLException {
          statement = connection.prepareStatement(getInsertQueryForHostName(),
              Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

          return getStatmentForHost(statement, tailHostName, primaryKey);

        }

      }, holder);
```

Comment: you can call the method in junit?

Comment: It is not cocering inside prearedstatementcreator